# How to download Google APIs using Android SDK and AVD manager (as it gives SHA-1 MessageDigest not available)?

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device, sha1

I cannot download the Google APIs using the Android SDK and AVD manager. Whenever trying I get the error below:

> SHA-1 MessageDigest not available

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27945813/842480), I think it's similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found either a work around or the right way to do this in a Windows XP environment:

If I only followed this to the letter:

> If you are developing in Eclipse with ADT, you can select Window >Android SDK and AVD Manager.

It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

For "normal" (I mean JDK / JRE for Java EE development, dont know about android) Java applications, the following holds:
If there is such a mistake as "SHA-1 not available" you to choose the right security provider.

There should be a file **$JAVA_JDK/jre/lib/security/java.security** in which you have to choose a useful provider.
On my machine the paragraph looks like this

```
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider 
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.4=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.5=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.6=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.7=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.8=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
```