# Cannot run sbt on redhat

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried downloading and running sbt on RedHat using:

```
curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo
sudo yum install sbt
```

, and I get this error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at xsbt.boot.Update.settings$lzycompute(Update.scala:76)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.settings(Update.scala:71)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.ivyLockFile$lzycompute(Update.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:350)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The SHA1 algorithm is not available in your classpath
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.<clinit>(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:86)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA1 MessageDigest not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:167)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.<clinit>(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:84)
    ... 29 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Is it an error in the sbt initialization itself?

Since this is the recommended way to install sbt from the official website, what other ways of installing sbt on redhat would you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does executing activator give ExceptionInInitializerError caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA1 MessageDigest not available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945464/why-does-executing-activator-give-exceptionininitializererror-caused-by-java-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by installing the [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) jars onto my jvm installation, which were not present in my RedHat vms.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the latest SBT version and a proper wrapper run script for it. There is a very nice script for it written by Paul Phillips (one of the Scala lang contributors). I just have a little shell script `get_sbt.sh` that downloads the latest version for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Downloads the latest version of SBT runner script which in turn downloads
# SBT launcher JAR and provides lots of convenience methods.

curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > sbt && chmod 0755 sbt
```

You can run it like this:

`./get_sbt.sh`

It will download the runner script to your current directory, afterwards just run the runner script with:

`./sbt`

This in turn will download the latest SBT JAR and whatever else is needed will be bootstrapped from here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't get around to trying this out though.